# Combining echo and cat on Unix

Tags: unix, shell, piping

Really simple question, how do I combine echo and cat in the shell, I'm trying to write the contents of a file into another file with a prepended string?

If /tmp/file looks like this:

```
this is a test
```

I want to run this:

```
echo "PREPENDED STRING"
cat /tmp/file | sed 's/test/test2/g' > /tmp/result
```

so that /tmp/result looks like this:

```
PREPENDED STRINGthis is a test2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "PREPENDED STRING" | cat - /tmp/file | sed 's/test/test2/g' > /tmp/result
```

Comment: I like this simplicity, but for completeness should have the -n flag on echo as mentionned in another answer.

Comment: For anyone else wondering about the `-` in the `cat` args, from the man pages: `With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.`

Comment: The `-n` flag doesn't work on all variants of `echo`, but that is mostly a historical note.

Comment: I've always been using `{ echo "PREPENDED STRING"; cat /tmp/file; } |` but this is much more elegant, thank you!

Comment: Where the -n flag on echo is needed to suppress the trailing newline.

Comment: Note that the ``-n`` must come before the string: ``echo -n "mystring" | cat - astrophy``

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
(printf "%s" "PREPENDED STRING"; sed 's/test/test2/g' /tmp/file) >/tmp/result
```

The parentheses run the command(s) inside a subshell, so that the output looks like a single stream for the `>/tmp/result` redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use only sed

```
  sed -e 's/test/test2/g
s/^/PREPEND STRING/' /tmp/file > /tmp/result
```

Comment: for "one-liner-ness" use 2 `-e`'s:  `sed -e 's/test/test2/g' -e 's/^/PREPEND STRING/' ...`

Comment: This of course will prepend the string to every line of the input file.

Comment: Which may be what's wanted. If not: `sed '1s/^/PREPENDED STRING/; s/test/test2/g' /tmp/file > /tmp/result`

Answer (score 2):

Or also:

```
{ echo "PREPENDED STRING" ; cat /tmp/file | sed 's/test/test2/g' } > /tmp/result
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`, e.g. this would also work: `{ echo "PREPENDED STRING" ; sed 's/test/test2/g'; } < /tmp/file > /tmp/result`

Answer (score 1):

If this is ever for sending an e-mail, remember to use CRLF line-endings, like so:

```
echo -e 'To: cookimonster@kibo.org\r' | cat - body-of-message \
| sed 's/test/test2/g' | sendmail -t
```

Notice the **-e**-flag and the **\r** inside the string.

Setting To: this way in a loop gives you the world's simplest bulk-mailer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:  assuming the prepended string should only appear once and not for every line:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {printf("%s","PREPEND STRING")} {gsub(/test/, "&2")} 1' in > out
```